# Make DVD image in Mac OS X without third-party tools?

Tags: mac-osx, optical-media

Is there any way in Mac OS X 10.5.x to create a .dmg image from existing physical DVD, without a third-party tools installation? I have carefully examined "disk utility" and searched Google, but it seems that all people just write .dmg files, no information on how to create them from physical DVD disks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Launch Disk Utility
2. Select the icon for the CD/DVD you want to image
3. Click the "New Image" button
4. Choose "DVD/CD Master" as the image format, this creates a CDR image (an ISO basically) which is the only *block-level* image format available in the Disk Utility GUI (and also the only format you can easily mount in Windows should you want to)
5. Save

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried dd?

You can create an iso of the DVD in the following manner.

```
*Open a new terminal*
mount <look for the entry that says /dev/sdX DVD/CD ROM>
dd if=/dev/sdX of=dvdimage.iso
```

This should be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Disk utility is able to do that. Just select the disk you want an image from in the sidebar in Disk Utility and then click the "new image button" in the top icon bar.

Added note: Of course this doesn't work with CSS encoded video dvd's :)

Comment: It's always worked for me with a CSS encoded DVD - as it reads the data on the DVD and doesn't care about the video encryption. You still needed to have somethin DeCSS the video however.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, open up Disk Utility - click on the DVD and then choose File -> Create New Disk Image from disk#s# (NAME_OF_DVD_HERE).

You can then save it somewhere (compressed or CD/DVD master) and you're good to go. (This does work with CSS'd DVDs)